# Jenkins Pipeline Environment Variable in Shell script creates a new line

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to access an env variable in Jenkins pipeline and want to use it in a Shell Script executing in the same pipeline but a differnt step,

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven 'M2'
    }

    environment {
        stable_revision = sh(script: 'curl -H "Authorization: Basic $base64encoded" "https://xyz.sad" | jq -r "name"', returnStdout: true)
    }

    stages {
        stage('Initial-Checks') {
            steps {
          echo "Stable Revision: ${env.stable_revision}" //displays the value
          bat "sh && sh undeploy.sh"
        }}
...
}}
```

This is a sample Shell script, it has many lines, but I have an issue in only accessing the above `stable_revision` variable,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo xyz = ${stable_revision} #### this gives the right value xyz = 22
echo xyz2 = ${stable_revision}/d ### here after the value the /d is written in new line
```

For example, let's say the `stable_revision` value is `22`, then in the SH script `echo` I am getting the value as,

```
xyz2 = 22
 /d
```

I want the value to be `xyz2 = 22/d`

Comment: `echo` adds a newline unless you use `-n`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.trim()` to strip off a trailing newline.

```
environment {
        stable_revision = sh(script: 'curl -H "Authorization: Basic $base64encoded" "https://xyz.sad" | jq -r "name"', returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```

> ***returnStdout (optional)***:
>   If checked, standard output from the task is returned as the step value as a String, rather than being printed
>   to the build log. (Standard error, if any, will still be printed to
>   the log.) You will often want to call .trim() on the result to strip
>   off a trailing newline.

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script

Answer (score 1):

If you use `bash` instead of `sh` for your commands, you can benefit from Bash's built-in string transformations

Here it trims all trailing characters from the `[:space:]` class witch includes actual spaces and newlines.

```
echo "xyz2 = ${stable_revision%%[[:space:]]}/d"
```

If `$stable_revision` is always an integer, you can force the shell to use it like an integer with:

```sh
echo "xyz2 = $((stable_revision))/d"
```

If you are sure that `$stable_revision` contains no space, you can force the shell to trim all spaces by using it like a table element:

```
sr=($stable_revision); echo "xyz2 = ${sr[0]}/d"
```

You can also use the automatic trimming of a sub-shell returned value, that would trim any leading, trailing and duplicate spaces in-between:

```
echo "xyz2 = $(echo ${stable_revision})/d"`
```